# Understanding the matching unit-by-unit in Propensity Matching Score?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores

I did an extensive research on more than 50 papers in Finance and Economcis using Propensity Matching Scores. ***However, there is no paper so far tell me how to match the unit-by-unit(firm-by -firm) due to propensity score.***

Clearly, the steps of working on PSM are:

1. Calculation propensity for each OBSERVATION based on pre-treatment unit characteristics (I highlighted here because in panel data, one unit (or firm) can have many observations (e.g. if we have 3 years before event, we can have upto 3 observations per firm, meaning 3 propensity score for each observation).
2. Afterward, according to tons of paper in finance, health, and economic, we match the treated and control units based on propensity score.

However, the propensity score at the first step is at the observational level when it is at the unit level at the second step. I tried my best but there is no paper explicitly tell me how to match firms by firm.

I found a paper that implicitly tell me that we can we can calculate the mean of characteristics of all observation per firm. Then we estimate the propensity score for each firm based on these average-values. However, that paper state something crucially wrong so it really harmful if I used that paper as reference for my choice. The paper I mentioned is [Howell, 2016](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0048733316301093?casa_token=WBG_hIMKwngAAAAA:Dqc3e3qqT2E0e9IAaOyg6VYsWVAxhPqJ0368kyDqCG_F1Hr3DdUMcX1r_DWsITqQAvvTuAftcixj#sec0060)

In that papers, the authgors mentioned twice supporting my idea about average characteristic above :

> Firms in the control group are matched to the treatment group on the
> basis of the pre-treatment **(1998–2001)** mean of these variables
>
> All covariates are measured by the mean before the policy treatment

But the problem here is he stated wrong here, his sample is from 2001 to2004 is pre-treatment. I am convinced it should be a typo, but it is a wrong statement. In another word, we cannot use that paper as reference in this case.

Comment: Have your read [Zubizarreta & Keele (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2016.1240683) or [Pimentel et al. (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1214/17-AOAS1118)? These both describe matching algorithms for this exact case (a clustered observational study with treatment at the cluster level).

Comment: Thanks @Noah, it sounds to me that they did not state how they match in PSM case directly

Comment: They describe methods better than PSM designed especially for the scenario you have. PSM is just one way to do matching, and rarely the best way.